# fit bxSlider to entire page

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, bxslider

I am using bxslider on a site that i'm working on. From the way I have seen it, The height of the slider is as high as the height of it's longest content, height wise.

So the slider is in a div of class home`(.home)` which is in the body element. I am using a small jquery function to set the height of the body to be as high as the window height upon loading or resizing.

```
function setdivheight()
{
    var win_height = $(window).height();
    win_height = win_height - 49;
    $('div.content-wrap').children().css({'min-height':win_height});

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        setdivheight();
    });
}
```

Question is, how do i Set the height of the slider to be 100% of the entire page at any given time . If it helps, i have set the html,body and div.home elements css to have a height of 100%. Please help